# How are Function objects different from Normal objects?

Tags: javascript, interpreter

How are functions stored in a variable?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

> In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) objects.

Suppose this scenario,

```
var fn = function () {};
fn.attr = 3;

console.log(fn); //prints function() {}

console.log(Object.keys(fn)); //prints ["attr"]
```

If a function is an object shouldn't it have keys and value kind where the function is stored in a property and the interpreters don't show that property? Something like C++ style operator overloading or array/object representation in Javascript itself. I mean to say are functions (or arrays) are just objects treated in a different manner? Which might imply that anonymous functions are stored in an object with a hidden property.

---

In summary, what is the underlying working of functions(or arrays)? Are they treated specially? Or are they just syntactic sugar for some hidden property which is called when `()` is used?

Comment: What interpreter are you using? In Node I get `[ 'attr' ]`.

Comment: I'm using Chrome console

Comment: @TarunMaganti I cannot reproduce this in Chrome. I get ['attr'].

Comment: Im getting `["attr"]` in chrome console

Comment: Edited the error. That is not the core of the problem though!

Comment: In summary, yes, the underlying JS engines store metadata alongside the Objects. Data you can not access in JS, but the engine needs to deal with the Object. In case of a function, such metadata would be wether this object is callable, or even more, wether it is constructable (can be used as a constuctor with `new`). In general, informations needed to optimize the handling of these Objects, wether there is some optimized Type stored for this Object or wether it has to fall back to a dictionary, ...

Comment: "*where the function is stored in a property*" - no, the whole point is that the object itself is the function. It's callable. It has a *hidden* `[[call]]` method if you will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, functions are special.**

**Proof**

```
const f = Object.create(Function.prototype);
f(); // TypeError: f is not a function
```

**Exposition**

They are "callable objects" that can only be created via prescribed syntax (function expressions, statements, declarations, fat-arrows, object literal method definition shorthand, `Function` constructor, `class` methods).

That means they have a special `[[Call]]` method (not visible to you) that is called when you invoke them with the `()` syntax.

`[[Call]]` coordinates:

- the creation of the execution context (call-stack frame)
- addition of the new execution context to the top of the stack
- execution of the function logic
- removal of the execution context from the stack
- cueing up the next context to run (the one immediately lower on the stack)
- supplying any return value to the next execution context

Creation of the execution context in turn completes configuration of the `LexicalEnvironment` (used for scoping), configuration of the receiver (`this`) for the function and other meta-logic.

Functions also differ from most normal objects in that they have `Function.prototype` on their `[[Prototype]]` chain (although you can create your own 'useless' object by inheriting from `Function.prototype` - see above).

For a full list of differences, please see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) etc.

Comment: Aren't objects special as well, in that they can only be created via prescribed syntax (object literals, `new` calls, `Object` function)?

Comment: "*configures the [[Prototype]] chain*" - no, you seem to confuse that with `[[construct]]`. But about the yadda, yadda: *executes body* would be an important part to add :-)

Comment: My mistake re the prototype chain. The specialness is a bit philosophical.